# Datagrid : Is there no Sorted event?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I need to know when a **WPF Datagrid** has been sorted by the user.  Why is there no `Sorted` event? I can only find a Sorting event.

I also investigated the `CollectionView` and `ListCollectionView` that is exposing the objects to the View, without any luck.

I am quite surprised as this should come out of the box.
Any ideas?

Comment: MSDN may be a better place to ask "why".

Comment: Handle Sort and just pass sort to the DataGrid.

Comment: handle sort? You mean sorting?

Comment: Please take a look at this post.
[Sorted Event][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416961/how-can-i-be-notified-if-a-datagrid-column-is-sorted-and-not-sorting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

datagrid has "Sorting" event, subscribe to it!

XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" anUserSortColumns="True" 
           Sorting="DataGrid_Sorting"/>
```

.cs code:

```
private void DataGrid_Sorting(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("sorting grid by '{0}' column in {1} order", e.Column.SortMemberPath, e.Column.SortDirection));
}
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer. OP specifically says he wants a Sorted event, not a Sorting event. The difference is whether the items have already been sorted. Oliver Dufner's comment pointing to a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416961/how-can-i-be-notified-if-a-datagrid-column-is-sorted-and-not-sorting) is the correct response.

Answer (score 5):

I've taken an example from [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752288%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and adjusted it to raise a Sorted event when the Sorting event is done.

```
public class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    // Create a custom routed event by first registering a RoutedEventID
    // This event uses the bubbling routing strategy
    public static readonly RoutedEvent SortedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        "Sorted", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(CustomDataGrid));
    
    // Provide CLR accessors for the event
    public event RoutedEventHandler Sorted
    {
        add { AddHandler(SortedEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(SortedEvent, value); }
    }

    // This method raises the Sorted event
    void RaiseSortedEvent()
    {
        RoutedEventArgs newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(CustomDataGrid.SortedEvent);
        RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
    }

    protected override void OnSorting(DataGridSortingEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        base.OnSorting(eventArgs);
        RaiseSortedEvent();
    }
}
```

Then you can use it either in codebehind.

```
datagrid.Sorted += new RoutedEventHandler(datagrid_Sorted);
```

or in XAML

```
<local:CustomDataGrid x:Name="datagrid" Sorted="datagrid_Sorted"/>
```

And here the method that will get triggered when the datagrid finishing sorting:

```
private void datagrid_Sorted(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
     var datagrid = (CustomDataGrid)sender;
     var sortedItems = datagrid.Items;

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can still subscribe to the DataGrid Sorting Event:

```
<local:CustomDataGrid x:Name="datagrid" Sorting="datagrid_Sorted;"/>
```

but to make sure that your actions happen after the sorting is done use Dispatcher :

```
private void DataGrid_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
{

    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
    {
        //runs after sorting is done
    }, null);
}
```

This way, there's no need of a custom Datagrid class.

Comment: this is a very simple and great solution, it works fine, thanks