# WPF Use DataGrid sort method before sorting itself

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a datagrid in my xaml:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" Grid.Row="1"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                          SelectionMode="Single"
                                          SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                                          IsReadOnly="True"
                                          CanUserSortColumns="True"
                                          Margin="0, 10, 0, 0"                                            
                                          Sorting="DataGrid_OnSorting">

                                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" CanUserSort="True"
                                                                SortMemberPath="CreationDate"
                                                                SortDirection= "Descending"> and so on...
```

And I want to sort my data BEFORE I press datagrid header, want to see my data already (!) sorted (ascending) using the method below:

```
 private async void DataGrid_OnSorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
        {
            var dir = e.Column.SortDirection != ListSortDirection.Ascending;
            var direction = (dir) ? ListSortDirection.Ascending : ListSortDirection.Descending;

            e.Handled = true;
            if (SearchModel != null)
            {
                var sort = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
                var searchKey = $"{_sortKey}{e.Column.DisplayIndex}";
                var paramName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValue(searchKey, null);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(paramName)) sort.Add(paramName, dir == _sortDirection);

                SearchModel.SortParameters = sort;
                await SearchAsync(SearchModel,false);
            }

            e.Column.SortDirection = direction;
        }
```

This method works perfectly but only when I press the header.
Watched this answer [Datagrid : Is there no Sorted event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571178/datagrid-is-there-no-sorted-event) but i don't know how apply it properly.

Comment: When you load `Items` in your View Model, sort it then. Not in the UI.

Comment: How are you pushing data to that `DataGrid`? Sort that data where ever you are getting it.

Comment: @XAMlMAX, good idea but I use pagination and the way you wrote I would sort only Items of corrent page not Items at all. Ideal variant is to use DataGrid_OnSorting method (cause it sort properly) but idk how...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ, good idea but I use pagination and the way you wrote I would sort only Items of corrent page not Items at all. Ideal variant is to use DataGrid_OnSorting method (cause it sort properly) but idk how...

Comment: Your `DataGrid` is bound to the `Items` property, so every time you will sort Items, you will sort the items in the `DataGrid`. Pagination will only affect the number of records that you will sort and if the Items don't have all the items `DataGrid` will NOT have them either. Is this really how DataGrid is bound in your app?

Answer (score 0):

Sort the `Items` source collection that you bind to or simply call the event handler, for example in the constructor of the view:

```
//sort by first column (index = 0)
DataGrid_OnSorting(DataGrid, new DataGridSortingEventArgs(DataGrid.Columns[0]));
```

Comment: i like your idea calling the event handler somewhere like constructor, but arguments of your variant are wrong and these ones DataGrid_OnSorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e) are wrong too. Could you give me a source to read about it or just say any other ideas of possible arguments

Comment: @АлександраЮреня: They are not wrong given the implementation of `DataGrid_OnSorting` you posted in your question. Did you try calling it? What happened?