# WPF DataGrid add separate border to every column set

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am trying to achieve effect where each column has its own border, but yet can not find a perfectly working solution.
[image]

This kind of look is desired but this is implemented by putting 3 borders in 3 columned Grid, which is not flexible as Grid columns and DataGrid columns are being sized sized separately

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3" xmlns:usercontrols="clr-namespace:EECC.UserControls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid Background="LightGray">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border Background="White" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="5"/>
    <Border Background="White" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Border Background="White" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="5" Grid.Column="2"/>

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ColumnWidth="*" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Padding="10" GridLinesVisibility="None" Background="Transparent" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a fair amount of elbow grease, you can get the desired look by extending the native `DataGrid`.

[image: FirstPic]

Custom header and cell templates should take care of the spacing, with the appropriate background color. The `AutoGeneratingColumn` behavior requires more control than could easily be achieved in XAML, so I chose to create the templates in code to be able to pass the column's `PropertyName`.

[image: SecondPic]

The observant reader will already have asked themselves: "What about the border at the end of the list?". That's right, we need to be able to distinguish the last item from all others, to be able to template its border differently.

This is done with the following contract:

```cs
public interface ICanBeLastItem
{
    bool IsLastItem { get; set; }
}
```

Which the row object needs to implement for the bottom border to be drawn correctly.

This also requires some custom logic when sorting, to update the value of `IsLastItem`. The pic with the yellow background shows the result of sorting on `ThirdNumber`.

The native `DataGrid` provides a `Sorting` event out of the box, but no `Sorted` event. The template thingy combined with the need for a custom event, led me to subclass `ColumnView` from `DataGrid` instead of declaring it as a `UserControl`.

I added code-behind to `MainWindow`, for switching the background color, but that's just for illustration purposes (as I didn't feel like implementing the `Command` pattern) and has nothing to do with the custom control.

The `ColumnView` is configured through binding. As always, feel free to extend. The current implementation expects the columns to be auto generated. In either case, the code for generating the templates is provided.

```xml
<local:ColumnView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Background="LightSteelBlue"/>
```

---

#### Demo code

### ColumnView

```cs
public class ColumnView : DataGrid
{
    public ColumnView()
    {
        HeadersVisibility = DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column;
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;

        // Hidden props from base DataGrid
        base.ColumnWidth = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
        base.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        base.GridLinesVisibility = DataGridGridLinesVisibility.None;

        // Styling
        ColumnHeaderStyle = CreateColumnHeaderStyle();
        CellStyle = CreateCellStyle(this);

        // Event handling
        AutoGeneratingColumn += OnAutoGeneratingColumn;
        Sorting += OnSorting;
        Sorted += OnSorted;
    }

    #region Hidden props

    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public new DataGridLength ColumnWidth
    {
        get => base.ColumnWidth;
        set => new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(ColumnView)} doesn't allow changing {nameof(ColumnWidth)}.");
    }

    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public new DataGridGridLinesVisibility GridLinesVisibility
    {
        get => base.GridLinesVisibility;
        set => new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(ColumnView)} doesn't allow changing {nameof(GridLinesVisibility)}.");
    }

    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public new bool AutoGenerateColumns
    {
        get => base.AutoGenerateColumns;
        set => new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(ColumnView)} doesn't allow changing {nameof(AutoGenerateColumns)}.");
    }

    #endregion Hidden props

    #region Styling

    private static Style CreateColumnHeaderStyle()
        => new Style(typeof(DataGridColumnHeader))
        {
            Setters =
            {
                new Setter(BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Transparent),
                new Setter(HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Stretch),
                new Setter(HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Stretch)
            }
        };

    private static Style CreateCellStyle(ColumnView columnView)
        => new Style(typeof(DataGridCell))
        {
            Setters =
            {
                new Setter(BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(0.0)),
                new Setter(BackgroundProperty, new Binding(nameof(Background)) { Source = columnView})
            }
        };

    #endregion Styling

    #region AutoGeneratingColumn

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643765/wpf-datagrid-databind-to-datatable-cell-in-celltemplates-datatemplate
    private static void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is ColumnView columnView)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ICanBeLastItem.IsLastItem))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                var column = new DataGridTemplateColumn
                {
                    CellTemplate = CreateCustomCellTemplate(e.PropertyName),
                    Header = e.Column.Header,
                    HeaderTemplate = CreateCustomHeaderTemplate(columnView, e.PropertyName),
                    HeaderStringFormat = e.Column.HeaderStringFormat,
                    SortMemberPath = e.PropertyName
                };
                e.Column = column;
            }
        }
    }

    private static DataTemplate CreateCustomCellTemplate(string path)
    {
        // Create the data template
        var customTemplate = new DataTemplate();

        // Set up the wrapping border
        var border = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Border));
        border.SetValue(BorderBrushProperty, Brushes.Black);
        border.SetValue(StyleProperty, new Style(typeof(Border))
        {
            Triggers =
            {
                new DataTrigger
                {
                    Binding = new Binding(nameof(DataGridCell.IsSelected)) { RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(DataGridCell), 1) },
                    Value = false,
                    Setters =
                    {
                        new Setter(BackgroundProperty, Brushes.White),
                    }
                },
                new DataTrigger
                {
                    Binding = new Binding(nameof(DataGridCell.IsSelected)) { RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(DataGridCell), 1) },
                    Value = true,
                    Setters =
                    {
                        new Setter(BackgroundProperty, SystemColors.HighlightBrush),
                    }
                },
                new DataTrigger
                {
                    Binding = new Binding(nameof(ICanBeLastItem.IsLastItem)),
                    Value = false,
                    Setters =
                    {
                        new Setter(MarginProperty, new Thickness(5.0, -1.0, 5.0, -1.0)),
                        new Setter(BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)),
                    }
                },
                new DataTrigger
                {
                    Binding = new Binding(nameof(ICanBeLastItem.IsLastItem)),
                    Value = true,
                    Setters =
                    {
                        new Setter(MarginProperty, new Thickness(5.0, -1.0, 5.0, 0.0)),
                        new Setter(BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)),
                        new Setter(Border.CornerRadiusProperty, new CornerRadius(0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 5.0)),
                        new Setter(Border.PaddingProperty, new Thickness(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0)),
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Set up the TextBlock
        var textBlock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        textBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding(path));
        textBlock.SetValue(MarginProperty, new Thickness(10.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0));

        // Set the visual tree of the data template
        border.AppendChild(textBlock);
        customTemplate.VisualTree = border;

        return customTemplate;
    }

    private static DataTemplate CreateCustomHeaderTemplate(ColumnView columnView, string propName)
    {
        // Create the data template
        var customTemplate = new DataTemplate();

        // Set up the wrapping border
        var border = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Border));
        border.SetValue(MarginProperty, new Thickness(5.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0));
        border.SetValue(BackgroundProperty, Brushes.White);
        border.SetValue(BorderBrushProperty, Brushes.Black);
        border.SetValue(BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0));
        border.SetValue(Border.CornerRadiusProperty, new CornerRadius(5.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0));

        // Set up the TextBlock
        var textBlock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        textBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, propName);
        textBlock.SetValue(MarginProperty, new Thickness(5.0));

        // Set the visual tree of the data template
        border.AppendChild(textBlock);
        customTemplate.VisualTree = border;

        return customTemplate;
    }

    #endregion AutoGeneratingColumn

    #region Sorting

    #region Custom Sorted Event

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571178/datagrid-is-there-no-sorted-event

    // Create a custom routed event by first registering a RoutedEventID
    // This event uses the bubbling routing strategy
    public static readonly RoutedEvent SortedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
        nameof(Sorted), RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(ColumnView));

    // Provide CLR accessors for the event
    public event RoutedEventHandler Sorted
    {
        add => AddHandler(SortedEvent, value);
        remove => RemoveHandler(SortedEvent, value);
    }

    // This method raises the Sorted event
    private void RaiseSortedEvent()
    {
        var newEventArgs = new RoutedEventArgs(ColumnView.SortedEvent);
        RaiseEvent(newEventArgs);
    }

    protected override void OnSorting(DataGridSortingEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        base.OnSorting(eventArgs);
        RaiseSortedEvent();
    }

    #endregion Custom Sorted Event

    private static void OnSorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is DataGrid dataGrid && dataGrid.HasItems)
        {
            if (dataGrid.Items[dataGrid.Items.Count - 1] is ICanBeLastItem lastItem)
            {
                lastItem.IsLastItem = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void OnSorted(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is DataGrid dataGrid && dataGrid.HasItems)
        {
            if (dataGrid.Items[dataGrid.Items.Count - 1] is ICanBeLastItem lastItem)
            {
                lastItem.IsLastItem = true;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion Sorting
}
```

### RowItem

```cs
public class RowItem : INotifyPropertyChanged, ICanBeLastItem
{
    public RowItem(int firstNumber, string secondNumber, double thirdNumber)
    {
        FirstNumber = firstNumber;
        SecondNumber = secondNumber;
        ThirdNumber = thirdNumber;
    }

    public int FirstNumber { get; }
    public string SecondNumber { get; }
    public double ThirdNumber { get; }

    private bool _isLastItem;
    public bool IsLastItem
    {
        get => _isLastItem;
        set
        {
            _isLastItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged
}

public interface ICanBeLastItem
{
    bool IsLastItem { get; set; }
}
```

### MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Switch Background" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" />
        <local:ColumnView x:Name="columnView" Grid.Row="1" Padding="10"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                          Background="LightSteelBlue"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (columnView.Background == Brushes.LightSteelBlue)
        {
            columnView.Background = Brushes.DarkRed;
        }
        else if (columnView.Background == Brushes.DarkRed)
        {
            columnView.Background = Brushes.Green;
        }
        else if (columnView.Background == Brushes.Green)
        {
            columnView.Background = Brushes.Blue;
        }
        else if (columnView.Background == Brushes.Blue)
        {
            columnView.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
        }
        else
        {
            columnView.Background = Brushes.LightSteelBlue;
        }
    }
}
```

### MainViewModel

```cs
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = InitializeItems(200);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<RowItem> InitializeItems(int numberOfItems)
    {
        var rowItems = new ObservableCollection<RowItem>();
        var random = new Random();
        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++)
        {
            var firstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(1000 * random.NextDouble());
            var secondNumber = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(1000 * random.NextDouble()));
            var thirdNumber = Math.Round(1000 * random.NextDouble());
            var rowItem = new RowItem(firstNumber, secondNumber, thirdNumber);
            rowItems.Add(rowItem);
        }

        rowItems[numberOfItems - 1].IsLastItem = true;

        return rowItems;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<RowItem> Items { get; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a great solution. It is great to achieve this by using DataGrid but it has two 'problems' regarding to my case. 1) Adding custom columns like DataGridTemplateColumn does not follow styling since currently it only works only on automatically generated columns. I guess it is easy to fix by defining a style or something. 2) From my screenshot it is shown that last visible row needs corner, in your case it is the actual last item. So bottom corner shall always be shown. Again, thank you for great solution.

Comment: You're welcome. To answer your questions 1) That's right, my solution is heavily template based, which maps nicely to the approach of automatically generating columns. Or at the very least, when you're using DataGridTemplateColumns. I basically did most of the 'framework' stuff, building a control that takes everything out of your hands. If you need more control, you can take it apart, use the bits and pieces and style those individually.

Comment: 2) I noticed that. That's really the other way around of conventional UX / UI, which (native) controls usually lean towards. It would require a sort of overlay like you used for OP. To keep that in sync with dynamic column widths would be hard starting from a native DataGrid.

Answer (score 3):

This is not trivial if you want to use the `DataGrid`. The "problem" is that the `DataGrid` uses a `Grid` to host the cells. The cell borders are drawn using the feature of the `Grid` to show grid lines. You can hide the grid lines but still you have the `Grid` controlling the layout.
Creating the gaps you want should not come easy. The layout system of the `Grid` makes it an effort to implement a solution that scales well. You can extend the `SelectiveScrollingGrid` (the hosting panel of the `DataGrid`) and add the gaps when laying out the items. Knowing about `DataGrid` internals, I can say it is possible, but not worth the effort.

The alternative solution would be to use a `ListView` with a `GridView` as host. The problem here is that the `GridView` is designed to show rows as single item. You have no chance to modify margins column based. You can only adjust the content. I have not tried to modify the `ListView` internal layout elements or override the layout algorithm, but in context of alternative solutions I would also rule the `ListView` using a `GridView` out - but it is possible. It's not worth the effort.

---

### Solution: Custom View

The simplest solution I can suggest is to adjust the data structure to show data column based. This way you can use a horizontal `ListBox`. Each item makes a column. Each column is realized as vertical `ListBox`. You basically have nested `ListBox` elements.

You would have to take care of the row mapping in order to allow selecting cells of a common row across the vertical `ListBox` columns.
This can be easily achieved by adding a `RowIndex` property to the `CellItem` models.

The idea is to have the horizontal `ListBox` display a collection of `ColumnItem` models. Each column item model exposes a collection of `CellItem` models. The `CellItem` items of different columns but the same row must share the same `CellItem.RowIndex`.
As a bonus, this solution is very easy to style. `ListBox` template has almost no parts compared to the significantly more complex `DataGrid` or the slightly more complex `GridView`.

To make showcasing the concept less confusing I chose to implement the grid layout as `UserControl`. For the sake of simplicity the logic to initialize and host the models and source collections is implemented inside this `UserControl`. I don't recommend this. Instantiation and hosting of the items should be outside the control e.g., inside a view model. You should add a `DependencyProperty` as `ItemsSource` for the control as data source for the internal horizontal `ListBox`.

**Usage Example**

```
<Window>
  <ColumnsView />
</Window>
```

[image]

1. First create the data structure to populate the view.
   The structure is based on the type `ColumnItem`, which hosts a collection of
   `CellItem` items where each `CellItem` has a `CellItem.RowIndex`.
   The `CellItem` items of different columns, that logically form a row must share the same `CellItem.RowIndex`.

**ColumnItem.cs**

```
public class ColumnItem
{
  public ColumnItem(string header, IEnumerable<CellItem> items)
  {
    Header = header;
    this.Items = new ObservableCollection<CellItem>(items);
  }

  public CellItem this[int rowIndex] 
    => this.Items.FirstOrDefault(cellItem => cellItem.RowIndex.Equals(rowIndex));

  public string Header { get; }
  public ObservableCollection<CellItem> Items { get; }
}
```

**CellItem.cs**

```
public class CellItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public CellItem(int rowIndex, object value)
  {
    this.RowIndex = rowIndex;
    this.Value = value;
  }

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") 
    => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  public int RowIndex { get; }

  private object value;
  public object Value
  {
    get => this.value;
    set
    {
      this.value = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private bool isSelected;
  public bool IsSelected
  {
    get => this.isSelected;
    set
    {
      this.isSelected = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

2. Build and initialize the data structure.
   In this example this is all implemented in the `UserControl` itself with the intend to keep the example as compact as possible.

**ColumnsView.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class ColumnsView : UserControl
{
  public ColumnsView()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;

    InitializeSourceData();
  }

  public InitializeSourceData()
  {
    this.Columns = new ObservableCollection<ColumnItem>();

    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < 3; columnIndex++)
    {
      var cellItems = new List<CellItem>();
      int asciiChar = 65;

      for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 10; rowIndex++)
      {
        var cellValue = $"CellItem.RowIndex:{rowIndex}, Value: {(char)asciiChar++}";
        var cellItem = new CellItem(rowIndex, cellValue);
        cellItems.Add(cellItem);
      }

      var columnHeader = $"Column {columnIndex + 1}";
      var columnItem = new ColumnItem(columnHeader, cellItems);
      this.Columns.Add(columnItem);
    }
  }

  private void CellsHostListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var cellsHost = sender as Selector;
    var selectedCell = cellsHost.SelectedItem as CellItem;
    SelectCellsOfRow(selectedCell.RowIndex);
  }

  private void SelectCellsOfRow(int selectedRowIndex)
  {
    foreach (ColumnItem columnItem in this.Columns)
    {
      var cellOfRow = columnItem[selectedRowIndex];
      cellOfRow.IsSelected = true;
    }
  }

  private void ColumnGripper_DragStarted(object sender, DragStartedEventArgs e) 
    => this.DragStartX = Mouse.GetPosition(this).X;

  private void ColumnGripper_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
  {
    if ((sender as DependencyObject).TryFindVisualParentElement(out ListBoxItem listBoxItem))
    {
      double currentMousePositionX = Mouse.GetPosition(this).X;
      listBoxItem.Width = Math.Max(0 , listBoxItem.ActualWidth - (this.DragStartX - currentMousePositionX));
      this.DragStartX = currentMousePositionX;
    }
  }

  public static bool TryFindVisualParentElement<TParent>(DependencyObject child, out TParent resultElement)
    where TParent : DependencyObject
  {
    resultElement = null;

    DependencyObject parentElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

    if (parentElement is TParent parent)
    {
      resultElement = parent;
      return true;
    }

    return parentElement != null 
      ? TryFindVisualParentElement(parentElement, out resultElement) 
      : false;
  }

  public ObservableCollection<ColumnItem> Columns { get; }
  private double DragStartX { get; set; }
}
```

3. Create the view using a horizontal `ListView` that renders it's `ColumnItem` source collection as a list of vertical `ListBox` elements.

**ColumnsView.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="ColumnsView">
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ColumnGripperStyle"
         TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
      <Setter Property="Margin"
            Value="-2,8" />
      <Setter Property="Width"
            Value="4" />
      <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Transparent" />
      <Setter Property="Cursor"
            Value="SizeWE" />
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <!-- Column host. Displays cells of a column. -->
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Columns}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Border Padding="4" 
                BorderThickness="1" 
                BorderBrush="Black" 
                CornerRadius="8">
          <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />

            <!-- Cell host. Displays cells of a column. -->
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
                     BorderThickness="0" 
                     Height="150"
                     Selector.SelectionChanged="CellsHostListBox_SelectionChanged">
              <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
                </DataTemplate>
              </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          
              <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
              
                  <!-- Link item container selection to CellItem.IsSelected -->
                  <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                </Style>
              </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListBox>
          </StackPanel>
        </Border>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,8,0" /> <!-- Define the column gap -->    
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
              <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter />
                <Thumb Grid.Column="1" 
                       Style="{StaticResource ColumnGripperStyle}"
                       DragStarted="ColumnGripper_DragStarted" 
                       DragDelta="ColumnGripper_DragDelta" />
              </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  </ListBox>
</UserControl>
```

### Notes for improvement

The `ColumnsView.Columns` property should be a `DependencyProperty` to allow to use the control as binding target.
The column gap can also be a `DependencyProperty` of `ColumnsView`.
By replacing the `TextBlock` that displays the column header with a `Button`, you can easily add sorting. Having the active column that triggers the sorting e.g. lexically, you would have to sync the other passive columns and sort them based on the `CellItem.RowIndex` order of the active sorted column.
Maybe choose to extend `Control` rather than `UserControl`.
You can implement the `CellItem` to use a generic type parameter to declare the `Cellitem.Value` property like `CellItem<TValue>`.
You can implement the `ColumnItem` to use a generic type parameter to declare the `ColumnItem.Items` property like `ColumnItem<TColumn>`.
Add a `ColumnsView.SelectedRow` property that returns a collection of all `CellItem` items of the current selected row

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, but it does not solve the question title.
It has these issues:

1) All items are loaded instantly, no virtualization is happening. 

2) DataGrid is required since now all it's features are lost.

3) It has vertical scrolling problem when mouse is over vertical ListBox.

Comment: 1) That's definitely not true. Both horizontal and vertical Listboxes virtualize their items. 2) Don't know what features you are missing that you can not easily implement yourself. But yes, it's not the DataGrid 3) Not sure what you mean here. I can scroll as usual. You should get more specific. But since you are not interested it doesn't really matter I guess.

Comment: I don't want to post a ton of styles or code. That's why I kept it simple with the purpose to show the idea that you can refine to meet your requirements. Regarding the vertical scroll, you can easily handle the routed scroll event and sync the scroll position of the other visible grids. Vertical scroll position and row index are synonymous. Then good luck with your DataGrid. I will not delete the post anyway.

Comment: I recommend to disable the vertical scroll viewer of t he vertical listboxes and use the top level scroll viewr of the horizontal listbox to scroll the columns.

Comment: 1) Generally ListBox has virtualization but not in this scenario. I tested it with 1000 elements and all of them were loaded instantly.
2) Features like AutoGenerateColumns,  manual column resizing and so on.
3) I guess you reproduced, it happens when mouse is over vertical ListBox.
Also you are right about not deleting the post because it is offering an interesting solution. And the max bounty is there to show my huge interest in this problem. And the title states that DataGrid is what I need. Thank you for further discussion.

Comment: 1) Virtualization is available. Of course you must assign a fixed height to the vertical inner ListBox. Otherwise it will tretch to make all items fit - and this mean it will load all items. But this is normal behavior. For the sake of demonstration I have added a height of 150 to the vertical cell host ListBox. If this was my control I would add extra properties to allow setting the height on the ColumnsView directly.

Comment: 2) I also have added column resizing. Took me ~10min. Autogeneration of columns based on a normal collection of random items will take me 10-15 min. including testing it. I would reuse the current data structure, but make it all internal. You can then use the control like a DataGrid. But I'm willing to spend this small time only if you are seriously interested. I have added some of your request to show how simple it is to add features. It doesn't compare to overriding the DataGrid.

Comment: Thank you for even further discussions, but DataGrid is really desired. As reimplementing DataGrid features is making things complex and less flexible.