# What event handler can I use to tell when a DataGrid control has finished sorting?

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid, sorting

I am simply wondering what event handler I can use to tell me when a DataGrid control has finished sorting. I know there is an event for Sorting, but I can't seem to find anything for when it has finished this operation. Any workarounds would be useful as well, as long as I can find an event that fires after the control is done sorting.

Here is the list of events on this control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid_events.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the sorting is done synchronously in the UI thread.  You can do what you want if you derive a class from DataGrid and override the OnSorting method.  If you call the base class OnSorting method, the sorting will be done when it returns.

```
public class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
{
...
  override OnSorting(DataGridSortingEventArgs eventArgs)
  {
    // sorting begins
    DataGrid::OnSorting(eventArgs);
    // sorting done
  }
}
```

This gives a more detailed answer: [How can I be notified if a DataGrid column is sorted (and not sorting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416961/how-can-i-be-notified-if-a-datagrid-column-is-sorted-and-not-sorting)

Comment: But then how will I know when sorting also begins?