# Datagrid sort, what happened to row?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, sorting, datagrid

I am coding a UserControl that can be use as a ScrollBar with color mark on it (like mostly all IDE).

My UserControl look

```
<UserControl x:Class="MarkedScrollBar" x:Name="Instance" ...>
<Grid Name="grd" >
    <COLUMN/ROW DEF>...</>
    <ScrollViewer Name="scrView" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
        <my:IcuContentPresenter x:Name="presenter" Content="{Binding AdditionnalContent, ElementName=Instance}" ContentUpdated="presenter_ContentUpdated"  />
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Canvas ...(Canvas place on the scrollbar) />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

On my UserControl, everything work fine. I can add content in my IcuContentPresenter (Extension of ContentPresenter to get 1 more event).

In my main window i use my MarkedScroolBar like this :

```
<my:IcuMarkedScrollBar Grid.Row="0" x:Name="bbb" Grid.Column="0" >
        <my:IcuMarkedScrollBar.AdditionnalContent>
            <my:IcuDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding AAA, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Loaded="DataGrid_Loaded" Width="300" LoadingRow="DataGrid_LoadingRow" />
        </my:IcuMarkedScrollBar.AdditionnalContent>
    </my:IcuMarkedScrollBar>
```

Again, i have a DataGrid extension to get 1 event (Sorted event, code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416961/how-can-i-be-notified-if-a-datagrid-column-is-sorted-and-not-sorting)).

Now my problem is that when i sort my datagrid Inside my MarkedScrollBar, i want the mark to follow the content, that the mark is binding to.

**First attempt**, I try to link the mark with the control having a Dictionary Key=Mark, Value=Control. I was getting the DatagridRow that I wanted to have a mark for my datacontext.

First time the datagrid appear, my mark are all well place, but if I sort, my mark don't follow. I went into debugging and saw that there is a DataGridRow that contains my datacontext item, but it's not the one i save in my Dictionary.

**End First attempt**

**Second attempt**, with the DataGridRow changing when I sort, I thought that if I was linking my DataContext item to my mark it would fix the bug.

So now, when I sort my datagrid, I try to find the datagridrow that contains my datacontext item. But it does find anything.

But, when i reexecute the same code manually with a button in the window, it's work. All my mark appear at the good position.

**End second attempt**

Brief explanation of my extension :

- DataGrid : I use it to get the Sorted event, because in Sorting event the row where not already move.
- ContentPresenter : I add event on it to get modification to the content, but not to the Property (like datagrid sorting). For that i needed to check the type of the content, so i don't support everything for now.

My code for the ContentPresenter is that :

```
public class IcuContentPresenter : ContentPresenter
{

    public event EventHandler<ControlEventArgs> ContentUpdated;

    public IcuContentPresenter()
    {
        this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    protected void OnLoaded(object p_oSender, RoutedEventArgs p_oEvent)
    {
        Type t = this.Content.GetType();

        if (t == typeof(IcuDataGrid))
        {
            IcuDataGrid oControl = this.Content as IcuDataGrid;
            oControl.Sorted += CallEvent;
        }
    }

    void CallEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ContentUpdated != null)
        {
            ContentUpdated(this, new ControlEventArgs(Content.GetType()));
        }
    }


    public UIElement FindVisualElementForObject(object p_oObject)
    {
        UIElement oTheOne = null;

        if (Content.GetType() == typeof(IcuDataGrid))
        {
            oTheOne = FindInDatagrid(p_oObject);
        }

        return oTheOne;
    }

    private UIElement FindInDatagrid(Object p_oObj)
    {
        DataGrid oGrid = Content as DataGrid;

        var a = (DataGridRow)oGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(p_oObj);

        return a;
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------
    // Inner class 
    //----------------------------------------------------
    public class ControlEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public ControlEventArgs(Type value)
        {
            ControlType = value;
        }

        public Type ControlType { get; set; }

    }
}
```

To support a control i will have to add them here. On the load of this control, I check the content, if the content is my Datagrid on the event Sorted i call the my Event ContentUpdated to be able to update my mark. But at this moment, it's like my datagrid contains no row with my datacontext item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When virtualization is enabled, row elements will only be generated for data items which are actually in view.  You will need to associate the marks with the underlying data items (row objects) rather than the `DataGridRow` elements.  The `Items` property on the `DataGrid` should have the rows in their correctly sorted positions.

Comment: When you say to associate the marks to the underlying element, it's not the same thing as my second attempt? I tryed to get the row that contains this element to update the mark, but the i didn't find a row when my event end, but when i lauch the command to update the row is find.

Comment: Not the underlying element; the underlying *data item* to which the element is bound.  The element may not be created if the row is not in view.  You only know the position of the data item in the collection; you don't know the exactly where the element will be, so you must estimate.

Comment: Thank for the anwser, it's a bit bad that i can only estimate the position, but I will do with it for now.

Comment: That's all the DataGrid's scrollbar can do anyway :).  It's one of the trade-offs of row virtualization.  You don't know how large a row will be, and you only generate and measure the rows that are actually visible.