# How to change cursor while sorting DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

When DataGrid (wpf) have many rows sorting can take quite long time (up to 5-10 seconds). How to change cursor to Cursors.Wait while searching?
I need somthing like this:

Xaml:

```
<DataGrid Name="List" SortStart="List_sortStart" SortComplete="sortComplete" />
```

Xaml.cs

```
void List_sortStart(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
}

void List_sortComplete(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
}
```

But DataGrid does not have SortStart and SortComplete events.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with the WPF/rendering architecture lacking determinacy when processing user interface updates; in this case, a DataGrid sort change. The DataGrid sort operation is begun with a mouse click on the column, which then updates the CollectionView, which finally is rendered visible in the DataGrid at a point later in time. To implement a mouse cursor change as you wish, you need to change the cursor to your busy cursor at the start of the sort operation, and then defer the change back to the normal cursor to a point in time when the user interface context is finished with its final layout work. LUCKILY THIS IS POSSIBLE!

First, one needs a reference to the main rendering thread's dispatcher. A simple way to get it is to create a class-level data item (in the code-behind .CS file) which is initialized by the main user interface thread:

```
private static readonly Dispatcher UIDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
```

Next, (in XAML) reference a code-behind handler for the DataGrid's Sorting event, which is executed whenever a sorting operation begins:

```
<DataGrid ... Sorting="DataGrid_Sorting">
```

The handler in the code-behind file looks like this:

```
private void DataGrid_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
{
    Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
    UIDispatcher.BeginInvoke((System.Action) (() => { Mouse.OverrideCursor = null; }),
                             DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
}
```

Note several things in the above code. First, when the sorting operation begins, we override the mouse cursor with the wait animation cursor on the first line. Next, we schedule code to execute on the user interface dispatcher with the **DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle** priority. This is the secret sauce that defers the code to change the mouse cursor back to normal.

The code to change the mouse cursor back to normal:

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
```

is only executed after the user interface dispatcher is finished with all of the processing of the sorting change/layout update logic and then becomes "idle".

There it is. This "trick" can be useful in many cases when coding for WPF. Put it in your quiver.

Comment: Why isn't this marked as the answer? This works like magic! Really helpful! I'm using this when I change the grouping and filter of my ICollectionView bound to my DataGrid's ItemsSource, which is full of converters to get summary rows of all the groups. The layout takes a lot of time to finish. I had no idea where to change the Cursor back to Arrow. And there you have it!

Answer (score 1):

`DataGrid` has `Sorting` event which occur when the sorting is about to begin. You can attach `List_sortStart` method to this event.

But then the problem come, as far as I can find, `DataGrid` doesn't have event that occur when sorting completed. One possible way to workaround this limitation is by creating custom `DataGrid` with a kind of sorting completed event, see the example in [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14155894/2998271)  :

```
<local:DataGridExt Name="List" Sorting="List_sortStart" Sorted="List_sortComplete" />
```