# ASP.NET Invalid Viewstate on Datagrid Sort if user clicks twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, viewstate

I'm having an issue on an older bit of code with an asp:Datagrid. This Datagrid has sorting columns enabled and if the user clicks too quickly, before the page finishes reloading from the sort, an invalid viewstate error is thrown. I tried disabling viewstate on the control and then rebinding it in every page load but to no avail. Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: a loading overlay with CSS?

Comment: I liked this idea and wanted to use it but since we don't have anything like it elsewhere in the solution it didn't go over well with the PM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up having to disable the links client side once a link was clicked. I used jquery to grab all my link tags in the DataGrid (since the only ones I had in there were in the header) and gave them all a click event that, once clicked, gave all link tags another click event that prevented the click.

To whit:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#<%=myDataGrid.ClientID%> a").on("click", function() {
        $("#<%=myDataGrid.ClientID a").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
```

In this way only the first click fires and all others are prevented until after the page refreshes from the post back.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but have you tried disabling sorting first thing inside the sorting event handler and then enabling it after the databind?

```
<asp:DataGrid id="MyDataGrid" OnSortCommand="SortMyData" AllowSorting="True" runat="server">

void SortMyData(Object sender, DataGridSortCommandEventArgs e)
{
    MyDataGrid.AllowSorting = false;
    DataView myDataView = [however you're retrieving the data];
    myDataView.Sort = e.SortExpression;
    MyDataGrid.DataSource = myDataView;
    MyDataGrid.DataBind();
    MyDataGrid.AllowSorting = true;
}
```

Or (probably better) implement an event for when the list is finished sorting like here: [How can I be notified if a DataGrid column is sorted (and not sorting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416961/how-can-i-be-notified-if-a-datagrid-column-is-sorted-and-not-sorting) and turn it back on then.

Comment: My issue here is that this didn't stop things before they got to the postback and then it was already too late. I ended up having to adjust client side. I'll post my solution below.